# Refresh R console without quitting the session?

Tags: r, settings

I usually open the R console all day long, but sometimes I need to clean my history and my workspace's background so that I can test functions or load new data.

I'm wondering whether there is an easier way to use a command line in .Rprofile so that I can refresh the R console without quitting or rebooting my current session.

What I have usually done for this is to `q()` without saving and then start R again and clean the History. I think somebody here might be able to give me some better suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the history have to do with testing functions? Maybe you are talking about clearing the workspace? `rm(list = ls())` If you want to add something to your .Rprofile to clear the screen, `cat('\014')` will take care of that

Comment: Yes, I clarified my question.

Comment: How to add a short cut of `rma<-rm(list = ls())` to .Rprofile so that I type `rma` will clean workspace? I tried`rma<-fucntion() rm(list=ls())`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `rm` and `ls` look in the current environment. If you put them in a function, the function becomes the current environment, so any variables you create within the function will be the removable ones, not the stuff in your workspace. You can explicitly tell `rm` and `ls` to search the global with `.rma <- function() rm(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)` Note the `.rma` instead of `rma`. The extra dot keeps the function hidden from `ls`, and the function won't remove itself. You can see hidden (dot) objects with `ls(all = TRUE)` and remove those, too, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For what concerns history, in *UNIX-like* systems (mine is Debian) this command refreshes it

```
loadhistory("")
```

However, as said in comments, `loadhistory` seems to be platform-dependent.

Check your `?loadhistory` if present on your platform. Mine says:

```
There are several history mechanisms available for the different
R consoles, which work in similar but not identical ways. There
are separate versions of this help file for Unix and Windows.
The functions described here work on Unix-alikes under the
readline command-line interface but may not otherwise (for
example, in batch use or in an embedded application)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got an error `> loadhistory("")
Error in .External2(C_loadhistory, file) : 
  'loadhistory' is not currently implemented`?

Comment: mmm `loadhistory` seems to be platform-dependent... see your `?loadhistory` if you can find a solution. Mine says `There are several history mechanisms available for the different R consoles, which work in similar but not identical ways. There are separate versions of this help file for Unix and Windows.
The functions described here work on Unix-alikes under the readline command-line interface but may not otherwise (for example, in batch use or in an embedded application)`

Comment: i don't get why the -1... since i'm a Unix user i couldn't try it on other platform... after all the answer as edited/qualified is correct

Comment: I don't know who did that, but I appreciate your efforts +1.